# Magento 2: Column is exists but throwing Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'so.event_id' in 'where clause' while inserting into sales_order

Tags: magento2, php, database

I have event_id column in my sales_order table. I want to place an order & I am not sending event_id because its zero by default. When am trying to place an order, Its throwing me the error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'so.event_id' in 'where clause', query was: INSERT INTO sales_order ...

[image]

I have already run all cache & upgrade commands many times but I don't know why its doing this. Here is my code:

```
public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData["entity"]["customer_email"]); // load customet by email address
        if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
            echo "Customer does not exist. please create here...";
            exit;
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote = $this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
        //add items in quote
        foreach ($orderData["entity"]["items"] as $item) {
            $product = $this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct(
                    $product, intval($item['qty_ordered'])
            );
        }

        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData["entity"]["billing_address"]);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod($orderData["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["method"]); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod($orderData["entity"]["payment"]["method"]); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => $orderData["entity"]["payment"]["method"]]);
//        $quote->setData('event_id', $orderData["entity"]["event_id"]);
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();

        // Create Order From Quote
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if ($order->getEntityId()) {
            $result['order_id'] = $order->getRealOrderId();
        } else {
            $result = ['error' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

I am calling this function in placeGTOrder($post) function where $post is my $orderData. Here is the function on which am sending my request as an action:

```
public function placeGTOrder($post) {
        $formData = $this->_helper->unserializeForm($post['formData']);
        $order = array();

        //fill cart items to order items 
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $getItems = [];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $collect = array();
            $collect["base_original_price"] = 45;
            $collect["base_price"] = 45;
            $collect["base_price_incl_tax"] = 45;
            $collect["base_row_invoiced"] = 0;
            $collect["base_row_total"] = 45;
            $collect["base_tax_amount"] = 0;
            $collect["base_tax_invoiced"] = 0;
            $collect["discount_amount"] = 4.5;
            $collect["discount_percent"] = 10;
            $collect["free_shipping"] = 0;
            $collect["is_virtual"] = 0;
            $collect["name"] = $item->getName();
            $collect["original_price"] = 45;
            $collect["price"] = 45;
            $collect["price_incl_tax"] = 45;
            $collect["product_id"] = $item->getProductId();
            $collect["product_type"] = "simple";
            $collect["qty_ordered"] = $item->getQty();
            $collect["row_total"] = 45;
            $collect["row_total_incl_tax"] = 45;
            $collect["sku"] = $item->getSku();
            $collect["store_id"] = 1;
            $getItems[] = $collect;
        }


//        $order["entity"]["event_id"] = $formData["eventID"];
        $order["entity"]["base_currency_code"] = "USD";
        $order["entity"]["base_discount_amount"] = -4.5;
        $order["entity"]["base_grand_total"] = 45.5;
        $order["entity"]["base_shipping_amount"] = 5;
        $order["entity"]["base_subtotal"] = 45;
        $order["entity"]["base_tax_amount"] = 0;
        $order["entity"]["customer_email"] = urldecode($formData['Email']);
        $order["entity"]["customer_firstname"] = $formData['FirstName'];
        $order["entity"]["customer_group_id"] = 3;
        $order["entity"]["customer_id"] = $formData['selected_customer_id'];
        $order["entity"]["customer_is_guest"] = 0;
        $order["entity"]["customer_lastname"] = $formData['LastName'];
        $order["entity"]["customer_note_notify"] = 1;
        $order["entity"]["discount_amount"] = -4.5;
        $order["entity"]["email_sent"] = 1;
        $order["entity"]["coupon_code"] = "";
        $order["entity"]["discount_description"] = "Test1";
        $order["entity"]["grand_total"] = 45.5;
        $order["entity"]["is_virtual"] = 0;
        $order["entity"]["order_currency_code"] = "USD";
        $order["entity"]["shipping_amount"] = 5;
        $order["entity"]["shipping_description"] = "Flat Rate - Fixed";
        $order["entity"]["state"] = "new";
        $order["entity"]["status"] = "pending";
        $order["entity"]["store_currency_code"] = "USD";
        $order["entity"]["store_id"] = 1;
        $order["entity"]["store_name"] = "Main Website\nMain Website Store\n";
        $order["entity"]["subtotal"] = 45;
        $order["entity"]["subtotal_incl_tax"] = 45;
        $order["entity"]["tax_amount"] = 0;
        $order["entity"]["total_item_count"] = 1;
        $order["entity"]["total_qty_ordered"] = 1;
        $order["entity"]["weight"] = 1;
        $order["entity"]["items"] = $getItems;
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["address_type"] = "billing";
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["city"] = urldecode($formData['MainAddress.City']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["company"] = "";
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["country_id"] = urldecode($formData["MainAddress.Country"]);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["email"] = urldecode($formData['Email']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["firstname"] = urldecode($formData['FirstName']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["lastname"] = urldecode($formData['LastName']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["postcode"] = urldecode($formData['MainAddress.Zip']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["region"] = urldecode($formData['region']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["region_code"] = urldecode($formData['region']);
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["region_id"] = 19;
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["street"] = array(urldecode($formData["MainAddress.Address1"]), urldecode($formData["MainAddress.Address2"]));
        $order["entity"]["billing_address"]["telephone"] = urldecode($formData["PrimaryPhone"]);
        $order["entity"]["payment"]["method"] = "checkmo";
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["address_type"] = "shipping";
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["city"] = urldecode($formData["MailingAddress.City"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["company"] = "";
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["country_id"] = urldecode($formData["MailingAddress.Country"]);
//        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["customer_address_id"] = 2;
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["email"] = urldecode($formData["Email"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["firstname"] = urldecode($formData["FirstName"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["lastname"] = urldecode($formData["LastName"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["postcode"] = urldecode($formData["MainAddress.Zip"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["region"] = urldecode($formData["region"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["region_code"] = urldecode($formData["region"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["region_id"] = 19;
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["street"] = array(urldecode($formData["MailingAddress.Address1"]), urldecode($formData["MailingAddress.Address2"]));
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["address"]["telephone"] = urldecode($formData["PrimaryPhone"]);
        $order["entity"]["extension_attributes"]["shipping_assignments"]["shipping"]["method"] = "flatrate_flatrate";

        $result = $this->createMageOrder($order);
        echo json_encode($result); exit; 
//        $ApiResponse = $this->_helper->placeOrderByAPI($order);
//        print_r($ApiResponse);
        exit;
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: your code has `exit` after "Customer does not exist. please create here..." is this by mistake? and in Magento 2.2.3's table `sales_order` has not column `event_id`. Is this your custom column?

Comment: In my case customer is already exists so its not by mistake. Its perfectly handled. Yes event_id is my own column I have created custom attributes for orders according to magento and magento created this column in sales_order table

Comment: Okay, then this blog may help you https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-custom-attribute-to-api-response-in-magento-2/

Comment: There shouldn't be an `exit` anywhere in your code. It should be handled differently.

Comment: Exit is not an issue. I just want to insert an order

Comment: I have not written any query please review my posted images as well you will see query in error log screenshot. Its just an Insert query but its giving me an error for where clause how is it possible?